# Scala IDE throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/janino/JaninoRuntimeException

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting Runtime Exception for Spark DataFrame code when I'm trying to execute spark code in Scala IDE (Eclipse Version 4.7).

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
object Demo {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("Local App").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
    val spark=new SQLContext(sc)
    import spark.implicits._
    val data =Seq((1,"ab"),(2,"abc"))
    val dataRDD=sc.parallelize(list)
    val df=dataRDD.toDF()
    df.show() // Getting Exception here
  }
}
```

Above code is working fine when I am executing using spark-shell. But problem is when I use with Scala IDE. I am using Mac OS. Exception Message and POMbelow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/janino/JaninoRuntimeException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:930)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2860)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:637)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:596)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:605)
    at Demo$.main(Demo.scala:15)
```

**pom.xml**

`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Demo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

`

Comment: Do you use Maven?

Comment: Yes, Maven 4.0.0 that available with Scala IDE 4.7

Comment: Please update the question and provide pom.xml

Comment: I updated my Pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this issue.

**Solution:** In Scala IDE go to :

> **Help** -->**Install New Software** --> **Unchecked Contact all update sites during
>   install to find required software**

Below I have attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This is helpful bot Mac and window version of Scala IDE.